# ISubscriptionEndpointConnector and IRegistrationContext (configuring a connectable consumer with a subscription filter on Azure Service Bus)

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm trying to configure a consumer that can be started/stopped depending on a business condition. I know that I can use `IReceiveEndpointConnector` for that, but unfortunately I also need to filter messages from the subscription (I'm using Azure Service Bus).

I found that `MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core` has `ISubscriptionEndpointConnector` that I can use for that - and it seems that I can create a subscription with a filter - but I'm having trouble linking it with a consumer. The `MassTransit.ISubscriptionEndpointConnector.ConnectSubscriptionEndpoint<T>(string, Action<IServiceBusSubscriptionEndpointConfigurator>)` method allows only to specify the configure action, but it doesn't provide the `IRegistrationContext` (like `MassTransit.IReceiveEndpointConnector.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(string, Action<IBusRegistrationContext, IReceiveEndpointConfigurator>)` that I need to register a DI-resolved consumer.

Here's a snippet showing the problem:

```cs
_handle = _subscriptionEndpointConnector.ConnectSubscriptionEndpoint<SomeMessage>(
    "subscriptionName", cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Rule = new CreateRuleOptions { Name = "Only special", Filter = new SqlRuleFilter("state = 'Special'")};
        cfg.ConfigureConsumer<SomeConsumer>(???);
    });
```

Am I missing something here? Is there another way to acquire `IRegistrationContext`?

Comment: Yeah, that's a miss. I think it's worth adding those overloads in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I've also seen the commit on the develop branch in the git repo - it looks like this is exactly what I was missing.